# Let $C\ne \emptyset$ and $A, B\subset C$ sets so that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let  $f:P(C) \to P(C) \times P(C)$ be a function, where $f(X)=(X\cap A, X \cap B)$ for every $X \in P(C)$.
How do I prove that $f$ is injective if and only if $A\cup B=C$?

Comment: HINT: For a direction, note that $f( \emptyset ) = f(C \setminus (A \cup B))$. For the converse, note that $X=X \cap C = X \cap (A \cup B) = (X \cap A) \cup (X \cap B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assume that $f$ is injective. Then $f(A\cup B) = (A, B)$ and 
$f(C) = (C\cap A, C\cap B) = (A, B)$, so $A\cup B = C$ since $f$ is injective.

Now assume that $A\cup B = C$. If $X$ and $Y$ are subsets of $C$ such that 
$f(X) = f(Y)$, then $(X\cap A, X\cap B) = (Y\cap A, Y\cap B)$ and so
$X\cap A = Y\cap A$ and $X\cap B = Y\cap B$. So
\begin{equation}
(X\cap B) \cup (X\cap A) = (Y\cap B) \cup (Y\cap A),
\end{equation}
and since $(X\cap B) \cup (X\cap A) = X \cap (A\cup B) = X\cap C = X$ and 
$(Y\cap B) \cup (Y\cap A) = Y \cap (A\cup B) = Y\cap C = Y$ it follows that $X=Y$ and hence that $f$ is injective.